# Android - Parse a Nested JSON array with Volley

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I am really new to JSON Parsing and learning everyday.

I have a specific JSON response I have to parse but I am finding no luck doing it.

I am using Volley for Parsing Request.

Here is my response:

```
{
    "error": false,
    "message": "Favourties fetched  successfully",
    "code": 200,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "5f1980f8c42e1f60854c57e4",
            "type": 1,
            "status": 1,
            "favourite": {
                "_id": "5f118057f44ebd1cead089db",
                "firstName": "Bilal",
                "lastName": "Khan",
                "businessName": "Master Paint",
                "image": "https://welist-assets.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/profile_images/1592383845941-default_avatar.png"
            },
            "createdAt": "2020-07-23T12:22:16.731Z",
            "updatedAt": "2020-07-23T12:22:16.731Z"
        },
        {
            "id": "5f198084c42e1f60854c57e2",
            "type": 3,
            "status": 1,
            "favourite": {
                "images": [],
                "_id": "5f12d5345478a53584eca98b",
                "name": "Water Paint7"
            },
            "createdAt": "2020-07-23T12:20:20.680Z",
            "updatedAt": "2020-07-23T12:20:20.680Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am able to get the Array which contains 2 object, but I am unable to get the data inside the nested favorites.

```
try {
                            Log.d("Onresponse", response);
                            //converting the string to json array object
                            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                            JSONArray array = obj.getJSONArray("data");
                            //traversing through all the object

                            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                                //getting product object from json array
                                JSONObject favorites = array.getJSONObject(i);
                                Log.d("lenght", favorites.getString("status"));
                                //adding the product to product list
                                favoriteList.add(new FavoriteVendorsModel(
                                        favorites.getString("firstName"),
                                        favorites.getString("lastName"),
                                        favorites.getString("businessName"),
                                        favorites.getString("image")
                                ));
                            }
```

Here is my method.

Comment: Using volley is not recommended anymore, retrofit is much easier and every project uses it. Also manipulating Json Object is a big pain and I know of no projects who do it. Not to be rude but if I had to code review it I'd reject it without thinking. Have a look at gson, Jackson or moshi, which work very nice with retrofit or independent of it.

Answer (score 0):

You have skipped one level of nesting. By calling `array.getJSONObject(i)` you get:

```
{
    "id": "5f1980f8c42e1f60854c57e4",
    "type": 1,
    "status": 1,
    "favourite": {
        "_id": "5f118057f44ebd1cead089db",
        "firstName": "Bilal",
        "lastName": "Khan",
        "businessName": "Master Paint",
        "image": "https://welist-assets.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/profile_images/1592383845941-default_avatar.png"
    },
    "createdAt": "2020-07-23T12:22:16.731Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-07-23T12:22:16.731Z"
}
```

And you are trying to call directly on that object next `getString` methods:

```
favorites.getString("firstName");
favorites.getString("lastName");
favorites.getString("businessName");
favorites.getString("image");
```

When actually you must first get JSONObject named `favourite` and then call these `getString` method on it:

```
JSONObject favorite = favorites.getJSONObject("favourite");

favorite.getString("firstName");
favorite.getString("lastName");
favorite.getString("businessName");
favorite.getString("image");
```